# Wordpress media libray - uploads are grey

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront

Yesterday some of the last uploaded images displayed a grey thumbnail, and new uploads gives the same grey thumb and if I go to the url it says "file dont exist"

The rest of the images works - if I click on one of the images I can see it, and its displays on the frontend. The url are something like this:

```
https://site/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/image.jpg
```

But the copy link url in the attachement details gives a "file not found"
and looks like this:

```
https://site/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/image-scaled.jpg
```

Tried to deactivate all plugins, no difference. If I FTP into the server, I can see all the images in the upload folder, even the new ones I add.

The folders has the right permission.

We use AWS and Cloudfront.

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Have you checked permissions on the files, are they being served by CloudFront via S3 or from disk?

Comment: @ChrisWilliams Hmm. Not sure. The upload folder isnt in the S3 bucket, so would assume from disk. And the last folder in the uploads folder - the files have 666 as permission, whereas the other folders file shave 777. I cant change it do, no permission (on the ftp)

Comment: If you look in your apache error logs does this return any errors? If this was on disk it would normally output it here :)

Comment: Not sure how to find the apache log on aws. Checking cloudwatch but I cant find it, so not sure unfortunately

Comment: These are on the server in `/var/logs` :)

Comment: Ah. Tits in /var/log and not appache, nginx. No errors there. I also changed the permissions on the files in the latest folder in uploads to 777 via terminal - no dice though.

Comment: OK, can you see in the access logs any requests to those images (this would determine if its a server or CloudFront issue)

Comment: Also in your browser make sure to disable cache :)

Comment: Yes, example: 172.32.40.214 - - [27/Jul/2020:20:51:13 +0000] "GET /wp-content/uploads/2020/07/banner-2-1100x241.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 47 "https://site/wp-admin/upload.php?=808ac7e306" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36" "188.151.30.228"

Comment: OK check the entire path from the root of your wordpress upto `/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/banner-2-1100x241.jpg`. If `/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/` did not grant permissions then still you would not be able to access it :)

Comment: Looks like this (added rights after each directory). ```var(755)/www(755)/html(755)/wp-content(777)/uploads(777)/2020(777)/07(777)/banner-1-768x98.jpg(777)```